# Implement custom yii model

Tags: php, yii

I'd like to use a set of DBF files as my yii app's database. Please suggest a documentation for implementing custom models in yii framework?

Comment: Looks like, I need to implement CDbConnection and override CActiveRecord::getConnection() http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao

Comment: Honestly, wouldn't it just be better to export the data in the DBF files into a modern database?

Comment: Agree, but we want to use the DBF files "as is" from another system. We will have to periodically update the files.

Comment: That sucks.  Tell your boss he is slowly killing your soul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It partly depends on if you are going to use it as the only database or want to support multiple databases. If it's your only database and assuming you have the PDO driver, you can set up your database connection in the Yii [config/main.php](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-configuration) file. I don't believe it would support Active Record, however, so as @ktothez mentioned, you might be better off importing it to a database that does.

If you want to support multiple databases and have the PDO driver, you can set a new database connection via [CDbConnection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#establishing-database-connection).

Otherwise you could simply make your own custom class and deal with it that way by fetching your custom data, storing in an array and then use Yii's array functions instead of AR functions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing exactly what you said in the last para.